# Describe Cosets of subgroup $H= \lbrace 2^n : n \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ of $\mathbb{R}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra

"A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents this exercise:

> Describe the cosets of the sub-group:
>
> Subgroup $H= \lbrace 2^n : n \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ of $\mathbb{R}^*$.

**EDIT #2**

Thanks to [Matt Samuel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187867/matt-samuel)'s comment for explaining $R^*$:

> Usually it denotes the group of nonzero real numbers under multiplication.

**END EDIT**

I wrote a few values of $H$:

$$H = \lbrace 2^0, 2^1, 2^2\rbrace = \lbrace 1, 2, 4 \rbrace$$

But, I'm unsure of how to reason about the *cosets* of $H$ given the infinitely sized, i.e. $R^*$, $a$ in the coset $aH$.

Please point me in the right direction of this problem.

Comment: Your assumption/guess is wrong, and you can't possibly solve the problem without knowing what $\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$ and its group operation are. Maybe you should look up the definition before trying to solve the problem (certainly you shouldn't guess).

Comment: Usually it denotes the group of *nonzero* real numbers under multiplication.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^*$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers, i.e. $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$. Here, $$H = \left\{\ldots, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, 1, 2, 4,\ldots\right\}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the operation on $\mathbb R^\times$ is multiplication. Any coset of $H$ will be $$aH=\{a2^n:n\in\mathbb Z, a\neq 0\}$$

Note that if $a\in H$ then $aH=H$

EDIT: a few notes since it looks like this is all new to you. $\mathbb R^\times$ is the group of real numbers closed under multiplication. Since $0$ has no multiplicative inverse (that is, nothing times zero gives one), $0$ can't be in the group.

Also, there is not "the" coset of $H$, there are many different cosets (in particular, infinite) of $H$. One example here would be $3H=\{3\cdot2^n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$ is usually the set of non-zero real numbers under multiplication, of which $H$ is a subgroup. One way to find cosets is begin with the definition: $aH = bH$ if and only if $b^{-1}a \in H$ which in your case means that
$$
\exists n\in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } a = b2^n
$$
So, for instance,
$$
\ldots = (3/4)H = (3/2)H = 3H = 6H = 12H = \ldots
$$
Perhaps the book is looking for something better, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1 = \{2^n: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  Then the set of all the cosets of the subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{R}^*$ is

$C = \{C_1\} \cup \{C_1r: r\in \mathbb{R^*} \wedge r\not\in C_1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The cosets will be

$H$ and $mH$ where $m\neq 2^p;p\in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Could you please show how you came up with $m \in 2\mathbb{Z} + 1$?

Comment: I think you probably misunderstood, @learnmore. We're talking about real numbers here, not just integers.

Comment: @KevinMeredith;i edited it